# Is it possible to auto-fill a container DIV with my text?

Tags: css

I have a DIV container with fixed size. The text in it fills about 50% of it.

I need to make the text with certain size, but make the line spacing bigger to fit the DIV's height. That's because I don't want a white space between the end of my text to the end of the containing DIV.

Is there a CSS trick to have the browser auto-set the line spacing ?

Comment: You could try manipulating the div's `line-height` property.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you'll need JavaScript to do this if it can be done at all.

Comment: CSS has no property to vertically justify text in a block of a given height.  So the short answer is no.  However, if you would consider a JavaScript/jQuery based solution, please rephrase your question accordingly.

Comment: Looks like you'll need a really complex solution. What you can do is first define a width for your container, paste the text and count the amount of lines, then set the line-height to `height/amount_of_lines` to make it fill vertically. IF you use em's you can even control the div's height with the `font-size` property. Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/okequh/3/edit

Comment: Thank you all, but I've neglected the design that chained me. Truly appreciate it.